# sick tim no node?

Tags: ros, node, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have download the package for the sick tim 551.

When I launch, it says this :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [sick_tim/sick_tim310]: can't locate node [sick_tim310] in package [sick_tim]
```

I tested it first on my dev computer on ubuntu 14.04 64 bits and it worked. Then I tested on my robot on Ubuntu 32 bits.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219243/sick-tim-no-node-?/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A likely cause for this message appearing is if you cloned the package into your workspace, but forgot to actually build it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-10-17**:
or did not `source devel/setup.bash` (or whatever your shell is)

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-10-19**:
that's more like it, because I get from the depository.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-10-19**:
Weird!
it seems that my source was somekind corrupted.
I relaunch it using :

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
@TomSon: if you haven't setup your `~/.bashrc` to do this for you, you'll have to source `setup.bash` in every new terminal you start.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
Also: if @Stefan Kohlbrecher's answer solved your issue, please mark it as such by ticking the checkmark left of the answer.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-10-19**:
@gvdhoorn It's weird because it's the only package (for now) that I have to do this (maybe it's a issue with my shell, I also use TMUX)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
That would be strange indeed. I'd expect you'd have to do this always, or otherwise non of your ROS packages (installed in `/opt/ros/indigo/..` would be found.